# Why is R's mean function different than SciPy/NumPy?

Tags: python, r, statistics

Why are these different? I read on the R documentation that `mean` is actually [trimmed mean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mean) but I can't figure out how to reproduce this using SciPy/NumPy.

```py
mds_null = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1Zwb4pu", index_col=0, sep="\t")
mds_null.mean(axis=0)
# MDS1    4.394633e-16
# MDS2   -2.590520e-16
# dtype: float64
```

```
> mds_null = read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1Zwb4pu", sep=sep, row.names=1, header = TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
> apply(mds_null, 2, mean)
         MDS1          MDS2
 4.442518e-16 -2.714842e-16
```

Comment: While mean can be used to get trimmed means,  the default behavior is no trimming.  All the means in your example are essentially zero. What you are seeing is differences in round-off error.

Comment: Base R does not have 64 bit floats. It cannot track the same number of decimal digits. Do you really need that level of precision?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was just trying to port some code from R to Python and couldn't figure out why it was different.

Comment: was there a significant difference? because so far what you showed is comparing a 0 vs a 0, one being more precise

Answer (score 0):

Discussion above pointed out that these are due to rounding specs in different languages.